# list of dict and programmatic variable creation

Tags: python, xml, list, sorting, dictionary

What is the best way to handle data from a long list of dicts that needs to be grouped based on a unindexed(?) variable and filtered?

I have a list of dict that look something like this (there are more keys but these are the relevant ones)

```
[{'bol': True, 'location': 102, 'type': 39, 'value':293.3812}, ...]
```

The list is long (500k give or take) and I need to perform several operation on it to include; filtering by 'location', grouping by 'type' without knowing what all the types are, sub-grouping by 'bol', sorting by 'value'. My end goal is to get a data set (I'm thinking .xml maybe?) that will have 2 values for each 'type'; max 'value' of the 'bol' = True group and min value of the 'bol' = False group. Any suggestions on "the best" way to handle this?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like a pandas job to me! Do you know it? Is really popular for data analysis with python http://pandas.pydata.org/

I would suggest to take a look into this framework, because you could build a dataframe with your data, then the operations that you want to perform are tipical dataframe operations.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(your_list)
# filter bol == True only
df = df.loc[df['bol'] == True]
df['value'].max()
```

Comment: I haven't heard of it but that looks like exactly what i need. Thanks!